# Access double to SQL decimal using SQL Bulk Copy

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, sqlbulkcopy

I have an Access database that I am converting to an SQL database using sqlbulkcopy in vb.net.  We have currency values (up to 2 decimal places) stored in Access as Double.  When I convert these Access fields to SQL fields with type [decimal] (19, 2), a number like 81.6 stored in the Access field sometimes appears as 81.59 in the SQL field when converted.

If I change the type in SQL to [decimal] (19,4) then it shows as 81.5999.  The number in Access is definitely calculated and stored to no more than two decimal places.  Can someone explain to me why SQL is doing this?  It doesn't happen all the time... only in some records.

I've reviewed just about any article I could find that explains decimal types and I understand what decimal is (I think), but I don't understand why numbers **sometimes** get converted like this.  Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**
Here is the code that I mentioned below that I used to loop through all of the tables and columns to rename the aliased columns ending in "1Z" to their original names:

```
        Dim dtTbls As DataTable = cnnSQL.GetSchema("Tables")
    For Each drTbls As DataRow In dtTbls.Rows
        Dim sTableName As String = drTbls(2)
        Dim query As String = String.Concat("select * from [", sTableName, "] Where 0=1")
        Dim myCmd As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(query, cnnSQL)
        Dim myData As New DataSet()
        myCmd.Fill(myData)
        For Each colu As DataColumn In myData.Tables(0).Columns
            If colu.ColumnName.EndsWith("1Z") = True Then
                Dim sNewColName As String = colu.ColumnName.Remove(colu.ColumnName.Length - 2, 2)
                dbSQL.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Concat("EXEC sp_rename '", sTableName, ".", colu.ColumnName, "', '", sNewColName, "', 'COLUMN'"))
            End If
        Next colu
    Next drTbls
```

Comment: SQL/server has a really good import utility that does a very good job of migrating data from Access. Have you considered using it instead of writing a bespoke migration ?

Comment: Hi.  Unfortunately, we require our own converter because we need to make a number of changes to end-user's databases at the same time as the conversion.  But thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that floating-point types like `Double` often cannot store numbers **exactly**, even values which seem to be quite "simple" numbers to us humans. This can be demonstrated by typing the following  into the Immediate Window of the VBA editor in Access:

```
?(CDbl(81.60) * CDbl(100)) - CDbl(8160)
```

The result returned is

```
-5.6843418860808E-13
```

Your experience suggests that a direct transfer of Access `Double` to SQL Server `decimal` will truncate the number instead of rounding it. Therefore, what you need to do is copy the values from Access into a separate SQL Server column of type `float`, and then use an UPDATE query in SQL Server to populate the `decimal(19,2)` column, e.g.,

```
UPDATE TableName SET DecimalColumn = ROUND(FloatColumn, 2)
```

### Edit

In case it makes things easier, it should also be possible to do the rounding and conversion on the Access side. You could create a Select query for each table that rounds the monetary values and converts them to `Currency`, like this...

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, CCur(Round([UnitPrice],2)) AS CurrUnitPrice
FROM Products;
```

...and then `SqlBulkCopy` the query instead of the table.

### Edit

As you may have discovered, trying to convert a column while retaining the original column name with a query like...

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, CCur(Round([UnitPrice],2)) AS UnitPrice
FROM Products
```

...results in the error

> Circular reference cause by alias 'UnitPrice' in query definition's SELECT list

A workaround for that issue would be to use a query like this:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, CurrUnitPrice AS UnitPrice
FROM
(
    SELECT ProductID, ProductName, CCur(Round([UnitPrice],2)) AS CurrUnitPrice
    FROM Products
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  But boy, I wish there was an easier way around this.  I have a ton of tables and Double columns that I need to bring over.  I knew SqlBulkCopy was too good to be true!

Comment: @MPITech Conversions like that are definitely tedious, so I updated my answer with an Access-side option in case it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that alternative approach.  This will probably work much better for most of our tables.  Your time has been appreciated!

Comment: Now that I am trying this, the bad part of doing it this way is that the column names in the target DB must match, so if I name the Access-side column something like "as CurrUnitPrice" then the SQL server side's column has to be "CurrUnitPrice" and then I have to go through and rename all of the columns afterwards in the converter.  There are like 50 tables like this.  You've been great so far... do you have any other ideas?

Comment: That's a great approach. I also considered adding "1Z" to the aliases so it would be "AS UnitPrice1Z" and then at the end, looping through all the tables and columns and those columns that ended with "1Z", rename the column without the 1Z. I actually JUST finished the code for that. This still requires a lot of query rewriting.  I am also thinking about a way to use a similar approach by first looping through every table and column in Access and checking if it is Double and then doing a round on it, but I don't think that would work.  What do you think about that approach?  Would it work?

Comment: I added the code I used to my OP, but still wondering if there is a way to do something similar on the Access side, modifying all Double fields so there is no need to modify all of my SELECT queries in the bulk imports.

Comment: @MPITech You could always try something like `ALTER TABLE Products ALTER COLUMN UnitPrice CURRENCY` on the Access side and see if that method avoids the truncation issue.

Comment: I just tried that and rounding first and ALTER COLUMN DECIMAL but with the original example, 81.60 in that one field still incorrectly came over as 81.59.  Looks like I am going to have to do things the long way.  I really appreciate your help.